# Is there a clearer way of representing dereferencing raw pointers and applying their functions in Rust?

Tags: rust, raw-pointer

I'm working with raw pointers in Rust and I've got a couple of lines which are really hard to read because I can't find an operator in Rust that has a similar function to `->` in C++. Does one exist?

Here's a snippet of my code in its currently hard to read state:

```
(*(*block).next().unwrap()).split(ExcHeader(30));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.  Raw pointers in Rust **must** be dereferenced manually, because doing so in an unsafe operation.

If you're repeatedly dereferencing the same pointer over and over again, you can just convert it into a reference (`let block = &*block;`).  Sadly, there is no postfix dereference operator, so there's not much you can do about the result of `next` being a pointer.